# Why does the GNOME installation guide say to use "meson _build" for GLib 2.62.2?

Tags: ubuntu, build, glib, gnome, meson-build

I am attempting to build glib 2.62 on Ubuntu 18/amd64 from source. Per the GNOME installation guide -- [Compiling the GLib package](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.62/glib-building.html) --
I am to use `meson _build`. **Is '_build' the name of a build file or is it a placeholder for the submodule I am compiling within the GLib package?** It does not appear as a file in the toplevel directory where I unpacked the source. I am new to the meson build system and if this is just a common placeholder for an entity I am unfamiliar with, their guide does not reference this whatsoever.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try the command and it didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

In `meson _build` the '_build' argument is a name for the build directory: Meson will create the directory and you must run ninja either inside that directory or with "-C _build".